# Can Google Maps be used in a desktop application?

Tags: .net, delphi, google-maps

Can Google Maps API be used in a desktop application (like Delphi or .net). but without embedding a web browser, I tried a few samples in `C#` which load static images but is it possible to load a dynamic map which is functional?

Or should I must use an embedded web browser for this? I saw some posts which mentions `JXMapKit`, does that kit also use a browser for enabling the functionality of the map?

Comment: Where would you like to show such *"dynamic map"* if not in browser ? Or what do you want to do with it ?

Comment: Right, just wanted to be sure i am not missing something, because my boss expression was "Hmm... a web container, that doesnt seem like a good idea"... so the only way is to use a web container. About what i want to do with it... I want to search for a location and then put marker on some specified locations but i want to be able to zoom in/out + pan the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **[Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/)** and **[CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/)** there is a **[TMapViewer](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=12674.0)**, which has these features:

- support **Google Maps** (Normal, Satellite, Hybrid, Physical, Physical
  hybrid)
- support **OpenStreet** based maps (OpenStreetMap Mapnik, OpenStreetMap Osmrenderer, OpenCycleMap) - these map servers can be used online or even run offline locally
- support **Virtual Earth** maps (Normal, Aerial, Road, Hybrid)
- support **Yahoo maps** (Normal, Satellite, Hybrid)
- pluggable download engine (synapse, native win32)
- disk caching

http://code.google.com/p/mapviewer

Comment: Thanks, but anything for delphi 7 or delphi xe3?

Comment: Not without embedding browser.

Answer (score 3):

> Can Google Maps be used in a desktop application?

It certainly can. After all, a web browser is a desktop application. You can embed a web browser in your application, and embed Google Maps in that. So clearly you can write whatever code is needed to perform the task of the browser and host Google Maps in that.

Whilst you could do this, it would seem to me to be an exercise in futility. You already have a solution that works perfectly. Use something like Chromium as a host, and embed that in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use google maps without web container, however, you could use some desktop map instead.